# How to Shrink Font in Order to fit Inside Width of View in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, textview, font-size

Let's say we have a single-line text view with a fixed width.  We want to display a string in it, but we don't know how long the string is yet.

We want the string to shrink as necessary in order to fit inside the text view without truncating.

In IOS, this accomplished with [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619625-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth):

**BEFORE:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

[image]

What is the Android equivalent?

I have consulted [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) and tried to test it out in code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tvc);
        tv.setText("aa aaa a aaaaaaa aaaadfgd gsfg fsdg dfs gdfs gds fg dsg dsg sdfg dsf g zzzzzzzzzz");

        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(tv, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);


    }
```

but was dismayed to find that it is not *shrinking* the font automatically to fit *width*, but rather *expanding* the font to fit *height*... with the string being truncated even more.

Please note: this question is different than ([Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)) because it doesn't have the same requirements: I am talking strictly about a single-line textview with a *width* restriction... and none of the answers in that question are satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [AutofitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview). In Android, autofit TextView is not native supported so you have to customize.

Answer (score -1):

either you use [AutofitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) or you can use the normal `TextView` with adding `ellipsize` property:

```
<TextView ...
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    />
```

This property will add three dots if the string length is more than the textview width.

Comment: "Adding three dots" is called truncating and it is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid.